# Converting a array of string to array of Int in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know I can do this:

```
a = ['1', '2']
b = []
a.forEach(function(e) { b.push(parseInt(e)); })
b
>> [1, 2]
```

I want to learn what is wrong in this?

```
['1', '2'].map(parseInt)
>> [1, NaN]
```

Comment: Also see my answer on [JavaScript: parseInt's radix mystery with Array.map](//stackoverflow.com/a/35180286)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way using `map()` by passing `Number`:

```js
var res = ['1', '2'].map(Number)
console.log(res);
```